# How to send binary data (0 volts, 5 volts) through USB?

Tags: serial-port, usbserial

I'm getting interested in electronics. As a beginner thing, I wanted to try to manually turn on and off my plasma globe through Python code. The globe takes in a 5 volt DC power supply. I can power it through my laptop, which is a nitro 5. So it's sending a constant 5 volts.
[image]

I need to communicate with the USB (serial port?). The module Pyserial seems to be the right choice. However, no matter what I try it can't identify the USB serial port. Not even when I plug in a phone. I think it can only identify a COM port, whatever that is. What's the difference? In my device manager, there isn't even a COM port section.

[image]

I know it's possible to communicate through that USB port because it can send data to and from my phone, so is this simple thing even possible? Thanks!

Comment: If the connector on that globe is a 2-wire barrel, then just power & ground are being delivered, and the USB differential data signals are not used.  So that globe would not be a USB device.  If you want to control this power delivery, a simple solution could be a USB-controlled relay.  You would also need another USB host port or an external 5 volt supply.  See https://superuser.com/questions/321774/easy-way-to-trigger-a-switch-via-usb

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that your plasma ball has most likely not USB interface at all, meaning that from the 4 wires you maybe got inside the cable (rx; tx; GND; 5V) only the 5 volts are used inside the ball to give the HV circuit power.

Other than that, pyserial is a meant to be used for serial communication like devices with RS232 not USB interface.

If i wanted to control the ball from my computer with software i would program an AVR µc to interact via serial communication (probably with an MOS-FET as a switch), from that point on you could use for example your python module to turn it on and of.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. OK thanks I'll look into it!

Comment: You don’t need an additional micro controller to switch that, the problem is rather in finding the proper hardware interface, which might require USB port to be in use.